# How do I get an array to work from a Series object that was converted from a dataframe object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe object that is converted into a Series object and then getting an array from it. However, the array output does not have anything in it. I have included a similar example to help with the problem. Why is the array showing none in it?

```
compensation1 = compensation.assign( 
    Total_Cash_Dollars = compensation.get("Cash Pay").apply(convert_pay_string_to_number)
    ) 
compensation1

Total_Pay_Dollars =  compensation1.get('Total_Cash_Dollars')

Rank
1        950000.0
2        950000.0
3      24890000.0
4       1000000.0
5       4650000.0
          ...    
98       930000.0
99       710000.0
100           0.0
101       40000.0
102           0.0
Name: Total_Cash_Dollars, Length: 102, dtype: float64


Total_Pay_Dollars = np.arange(Total_Pay_Dollars.loc[1],Total_Pay_Dollars.loc[102]) 
Total_Pay_Dollars
```

The output is as follows:

```
array([], dtype=float64)
```

Elsewhere:

```
attacks_table = bpd.read_csv('sharks.csv').set_index('Year')
attacks = attacks_table.get('Attacks')

Year
1930     26
1931     29
1932     27
1933     22
1934     27
       ... 
2013    122
2014    127
2015    143
2016    130
2017    136
Name: Attacks, Length: 88, dtype: int64

attacks_add = np.arange(attacks.loc[1930],attacks.loc[2017])
attacks_add


array([ 26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
        52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,
        65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
        78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
        91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103,
       104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
       117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129,
       130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135])
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. We don't have enough code to solve this, please share a [mcve]. You may also find the following article useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. As an aside, are you using `.get()` to access the columns of a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is trying to get the range (np.arange) between 950000 and 950000. Which is an empty array. 
Try this instead:

```
compensation1['Total_Cash_Dollars'].values
```